# execute rake task from .war

Tags: jruby, warbler

Is it possible to execute rake task from warbled rails project?

I have a warbled rails project deployed to JBoss. I need to run a mailer in background. What is best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, it's probably easiest to unpack the war and have a script inside that sets the classpath and uses the included jruby jars.

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/jruby/warbler/issues/10) with some ideas and a code fork. I hope we can have this built in eventually.

Comment: What would I set the classpath to? Would it be RAILS_ROOT/lib where all of the jruby jar files are? Do I have to use other folders?